# IDLE shell context documentation broken?

Tags: python, python-idle

Is the python-context-help feature in IDLE broken?

The context help feature in IDLE, if I understood it correctly, allows one to open the python documentation for the selected word:

1. highlight some built-in function, e.g print
2. press the default keyboard shortcut
3. the official documentation article for that function opens in a help window.

The default keyboard shortcut is Shift+F1. However, that shortcut, and any other shortcut I tried simply does not do what it's supposed to do.

Am I missing something here? Or is this feature broken.

Comment: Shift-F1 is for opening the documentation

Comment: In the config-keys.def file there are two shortcut definitions:

python-docs=<Key-F1>    and     

python-context-help=<Shift-Key-F1>

Comment: @Mondher You are correct. Shift-F1 and F1 both open python docs!!

Comment: @Derek 
Is that the intended way it is supposed to work, or is it a bug/oversight by the devs? I am used to the context help in other IDEs like Mathematica, it's extremely helpful. And I thought IDLE has it. But it seems it doesn't.

Anyway, I found an alternative solution: opening a second shell window, and start a help shell there and whenever I need the def or docs of some function, I just type it there and it gives me a quick summary of it.

Answer (score 0):

Oversight? I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue44574 with this post:

> The config.IdleConf.GetCoreKeys keyBindings dict contains
> '<>': ['']
> The was included in the initial version by Steven Gava, 9930061c, on 2001 Dec 2.  So it appears in the Keys page of the config dialog, as noticed by Mondher on SO (([IDLE shell context documentation broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263769/idle-shell-context-documentation-broken))

> The string does not appear elsewhere in idlelib, nor is the feature mentioned in the IDLE doc.  So it is unimplemented and undocumented.  Based on experience with other IDEs (Mathematica) Mondher suggests that one should be able to select a word and have it looked up in the index of the document opened by python-doc F1.  'Very useful' he says.

> On Windows, F1 opens an offline Windows help window with the Python docs.  Currently, modifier(s)-F1 is interpreted as F1 and the help window is opened.  I presume a shift-F1 binding will override that. I also presume that an argument can be added to the Windows open-help command.

> I don't know about online docs on other systems and don't think we can access indexes on opened python webpages.  Where shift-F1 does not work, a message should be displayed.

> If we decided to not implement index search anywhere, the line in config.py should be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm glad that by asking this question and with your help, I "contributed," even if it's an infinitesimally small one. I assume a real contextual help would be very helpful.

Comment: I think this is at least the 3rd bug reported here, on SO, that had not  been reported on the bpo tracker.